# Error #2036: Load Never Completed. URL: http://airdownload.adobe.com/air/browserapi/air.swf

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

UPDATE;

I've managed to reproduce this problem explained below locally - by disconnecting the local machine and clearing the browser cache. So the real question is; how can you load the air.swf file from a machine that is not connected to the 'net ? Or is there another way to launch an AIR application from SWF?

I have an AS3 application that is trying to launch a AIR application - it starts by loading the AIR SWF object and finding the currently installed version. My problem is that the AIR SWF object won't load. My code currently looks like the following;

```
private function getInstalledVersion():void {
    var airLoader_adobe:Loader = new Loader();
    loaderReferences["airLoader"] = airLoader_adobe;

    airLoader_adobe.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, function(event:Event):void{
        airswf = event.target.content;
        trace(new Date(), "-- contentLoaderInfo airswf loaded, status =", airswf.getStatus(), "; fetching currently installed version");
        airswf.getApplicationVersion(applicationId, publisherId, updateInstalledVersion); 
        delete loaderReferences["airLoader"];
    });

    airLoader_adobe.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, function ( event:IOErrorEvent ):void
    {
        trace(new Date(), "-- contentLoaderInfo IO_ERROR;", event.target, event.toString());
        delete loaderReferences["airLoader"];
    });

    var context_adobe:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext();
    airLoader_adobe.load(new URLRequest('http://airdownload.adobe.com/air/browserapi/air.swf'), context_adobe);
}
```

Now, this works just fine in my local development environment. And in the local test environments. But for reason it's failing with an IO_ERROR in the customer environment; I'm getting the following in the logs ...

```
Thu Oct 23 15:41:31 GMT+0100 2014 -- contentLoaderInfo IO_ERROR; [object LoaderInfo] [IOErrorEvent type="ioError" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 text="Error #2036: Load Never Completed. URL: http://airdownload.adobe.com/air/browserapi/air.swf"]
```

I'm at a bit of a loss as to what can be causing this as I just can't reproduce this error locally. I'm told AIR is installed (and if I uninstall AIR locally I get a different error from that shown). I know the PC doesn't have access to the internet, but again locally if I disconnect from the network it's not required.

The only thing I can think of is that there is a policy on the Windows PC that is somehow blocking the loading of AIR within my SWF application - but I've no idea what this could be.

Does anyone have any pointers as to what could be going wrong, here?

Thanks.

Comment: This is often the result of garbage collection. The loader gets disposed of before it finishes its job. Turn it into a member variable.

Comment: I've already got a member level Dictionary, defined as;

`private var loaderReferences:Dictionary = new Dictionary();`

which I put the loader in. I would expect that to prevent the GC from kicking in.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, just to make sure I'm understanding it right:

1. You're downloading the air.swf in an AS3 project? Why not compile an AIR project directly?
2. You're trying to download the air.swf on a machine not connected to the internet? Of course you can't download something from the internet if you're not connected?
3. What do you mean by "customer environment?" Are you saying it works on your computer but not your customer's? Or is it when you run on your own computer in "developer mode" and "customer mode?" What does that mean?

Have you tried downloading something else? Like a random image from a server? Does that have the same result?

Sorry to put these questions in an "answer," but I think it'd be too long for a comment. Let me know and maybe I can help figure it out

Comment: > 1. You're downloading the air.swf in an AS3 project?
Yes, I'm trying to launch an AIR application from a SWF app. Why? "Because" (I appreciate that the AIR app could be re-compiled as SWF, but it's not).

Comment: > 2. You're trying to download the air.swf on a machine not connected to the internet? 
Yes. And that's fundamentally the problem. How I can I load the airSWF object on an unconnected PC. Google suggests you can't simply host it locally.

Comment: > 3. What do you mean by "customer environment?"
The customers PC, which is not connected to the 'net.